# ¿Cómo puedo colocar estilos CSS sin que se sobrepongan?

Tags: html, css

Tengo esta estructura en HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el caso es que el `pagination a`, coge estilos de los `gallery-container a`, cosa que no quiero que ocurra, como podría hacer para que solo cogiera los estilos que le he dado en `pagination a`??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado colocar después del atributo la etiqueta !important. Por ejemplo: `color: black !important`

Comment: @Jok si, pero los atributos de margin, text-decoration, position y border me los coge del .gallery-container a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coge también esos estilos por que ese `a` también esta dentro de `.gallery-container`,
lo que tienes que hacer es indicar que los segundos estilos que pones se apliquen solo a los `a` que sean hijos directos de `.gallery-container` de esta manera:

```
.gallery-container > a { estilos }
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```css
.a > p {color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <p>aaaaaa</p>
  <div class="b">
    <p>bbbbbb</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Se puede solucionar con los selectores `class` e `id`.

El valor del atributo `id` de un elemento es único; es decir, no debería haber otro elemento con el mismo nombre de identificador (id) dentro de tu documento HTML. Dentro de los selectores que tenemos en CSS (por tipo, por clase y por id), cada uno tiene un determinado peso, siendo el selector de id el que tiene más peso.

Si cambias el `class` por un `id` en el div de paginación quedaría así:

```
#pagination a {
    text-align:center;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
}
.gallery-container a {
    color: black;
    height: 200px;  
    width: 80%;
    margin: 20px 100px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(227, 30, 36);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Y el html:

```
<div class="contenedor">
    <div class="gallery-container">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <div id="pagination">
            <a href="#">Pagina 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se más específico en la "ruta" del estilo:

```
.gallery-container .pagination a { ... }
```